# How to integrate SPRITER work ( project.scml ) with cocos2d-x 3.3?

Tags: cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0, skeletal-animation

I've made a skeletal animation in software called - Spriter. It's fairly good. When I save my project, It gets saved with extension - .scml.

How to use/integrate that animation project with cocos2d-x ?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: Not ZeroHacker. Not yet. You got one ?